# Liferay 6.1 carousel

Tags: firefox, liferay, liferay-aui

When using the carousel function in Liferay 6.1.1 CE GA2 I see the carousel working properly in both Safari and Chrome.

However, the images are not shown in Firefox.

In order to have the function working I created a Webcontent Structure with following code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<root>
    <dynamic-element name="activeIndex" type="text" index-type="" repeatable="false">
        <meta-data>
            <entry name="displayAsTooltip"><![CDATA[true]]></entry>
            <entry name="required"><![CDATA[false]]></entry>
            <entry name="instructions"><![CDATA[Index of the first visible item of the carousel]]></entry>
            <entry name="label"><![CDATA[activeIndex]]></entry>
            <entry name="predefinedValue"><![CDATA[0]]></entry>
        </meta-data>
    </dynamic-element>
    <dynamic-element name="timeInterval" type="text" index-type="" repeatable="false">
        <meta-data>
            <entry name="displayAsTooltip"><![CDATA[true]]></entry>
            <entry name="required"><![CDATA[false]]></entry>
            <entry name="instructions"><![CDATA[Interval time in seconds between an item transition.]]></entry>
            <entry name="label"><![CDATA[timeInterval]]></entry>
            <entry name="predefinedValue"><![CDATA[0.75]]></entry>
        </meta-data>
    </dynamic-element>
    <dynamic-element name="maxImageHeight" type="text" index-type="" repeatable="false">
        <meta-data>
            <entry name="displayAsTooltip"><![CDATA[true]]></entry>
            <entry name="required"><![CDATA[false]]></entry>
            <entry name="instructions"><![CDATA[Provide max height of image element. Min limit advisable is 40]]></entry>
            <entry name="label"><![CDATA[maxImageHeight]]></entry>
            <entry name="predefinedValue"><![CDATA[254]]></entry>
        </meta-data>
    </dynamic-element>
    <dynamic-element name="maxImageWidth" type="text" index-type="" repeatable="false">
        <meta-data>
            <entry name="displayAsTooltip"><![CDATA[true]]></entry>
            <entry name="required"><![CDATA[false]]></entry>
            <entry name="instructions"><![CDATA[Provide max width of image element. Min limit advisable is 130]]></entry>
            <entry name="label"><![CDATA[maxImageWidth]]></entry>
            <entry name="predefinedValue"><![CDATA[600]]></entry>
        </meta-data>
    </dynamic-element>
    <dynamic-element name="ImageElementSet" type="selection_break" index-type="keyword" repeatable="true">
        <dynamic-element name="image" type="image" index-type="keyword" repeatable="false"></dynamic-element>
        <dynamic-element name="linkUrl" type="text" index-type="keyword" repeatable="false"/>
    </dynamic-element>
</root>
```

And a web template consisting of

```
#set($imageWidth = $maxImageWidth.Data)
#set($imageHeight = $maxImageHeight.Data)
#set($imageWidthPx = $imageWidth + "px")
#set($imageHeightPx = $imageHeight + "px")
#set($interval = $timeInterval.Data)
#set($activeIndexValue = $activeIndex.Data)

<style type="text/css">
        .aui-carousel {
        -moz-user-select: none;
        margin: 20px 0;
    }
    .aui-carousel-item {
        border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
        text-indent: -9999em;
    }
    .aui-carousel li {
        margin: 0 !important;
    }
}

</style>

#set($totalCount = 0)
<div id="carousel">
    #foreach($imageElement in $ImageElementSet.getSiblings())
        #if($imageElement.image.getData() != "")
            #if($imageElement.linkUrl.getData() != "")
                <a href="$imageElement.linkUrl.Data">
                    <img class="aui-carousel-item" src="$imageElement.image.Data" height="$imageHeightPx" width="$imageWidthPx" />
                </a>
            #else
                <img class="aui-carousel-item" src="$imageElement.image.Data" height="$imageHeightPx" width="$imageWidthPx" />
            #end
            #set($totalCount = $totalCount + 1)
        #end
    #end
</div>

#if($totalCount > 0)
    <script>
        AUI().ready('aui-carousel', function(A) 
        { 
            var carousel = new A.Carousel(
            { 
                contentBox: '#carousel', 
                activeIndex: $activeIndexValue,
                intervalTime: $interval, 
                width: $imageWidth, 
                height: $imageHeight 
            }).render(); 
        });
    </script>
#end
```

However, it doesn't give what I need.

I appreciate your insights on how to get this working.

Comment: Would you please describe a bit further what you mean with "it doesn't give what I need"? What's the generated output with that template? Do you have CSS or JS problems?

Comment: What it doesn't give is show the images in a Firefox browser on my Mac.

Comment: Is the generated HTML what you expect? Use the Firefox Debug tools (or firebug) to validate.

Comment: The code generated is:
<div id="aui_3_4_0_1_126" class="yui3-widget aui-component aui-carousel" style="height: 330px; width: 960px;">
<div id="carousal" class="aui-carousel-content yui3-widget-content-expanded">
<a class="aui-carousel-item" href="bms4breweries" style="opacity: 1;">
<img class="aui-carousel-item" width="960px" height="330px" src="/image/journal/article?img_id=274711&t=1455186967874">
</a>

For a live view have a look at www.orrtiz.com

Comment: The carousel shows in:
* on my Mac:
** in Chrome
** in Safari

* on my IPad
** in Chrome
** in Firefox
** in Safari

Comment: Please do me a favor and edit your question with the DOM - and use the formatting options. It's hard to spot something in unformatted DOMs, however, at least I spot a `div id="carousal"` which has no equivalent in the template that you're quoting in your question. Also the DOM looks incomplete. Starts with `<div>` and ends in `</a>`

Comment: I see your live site and debugged a little. I found that text-indent css property in below css class is causing issue for firefox .`.aui-carousel-item {
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-indent: -9999em;
}` ...Removal of this property shows up the image in firefox. You may have to adjust this property for firefox.

Comment: @OlafKock Thank you for the feedback. Unfortunately I experienced that I submitted to soon (before reformating the text), and I couldn't fix it afterwards.

Comment: @PankajkumarKathiriya Thanks. That did the trick. Kudos!

Comment: @PierreSmits Putting above comment in answer so it can be closed

Answer (score 1):

I see your live site and debugged a little and I found that text-indent css property in below css class is causing issue for firefox.

`.aui-carousel-item { border-radius: 10px; text-indent: -9999em; }`

Removal of text-indent css property shows up the image in firefox so You may have to adjust this css property for firefox.